# remove browser password save dialog box when press submit in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I am using html:password field in my application,when submit the form browser show a pop up dialog box to save password.I want to remove this dialog option from my application ,i use autocomplete="off" option which hide all the cached info.But how to stop this dialog box appear after form submit.

Comment: Just don't. Seriously, do not interfere with expected and thoroughly engineered behaviour. If the users wanted, they would have disabled password saving.

Comment: In response to the posted answers: this feature is connected to the browser recognizing login credentials, and trying to be more conveniant for its user. If you want to circumvent this behaviour, you'd have to trick the browser to not recognize this username and password, wich boils down to not using a `input[type=password]` field. And this is where it gets **dangerous**, because now you're **compromizing the security** of the passwords of your customers, just so that a browser dialogue doesn't show up, wich every user can disable if he/she would want to.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following code i hope it will help.

```
<input type="text" id="username" name="username"/>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password"/>

<form id="theForm" action="" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenUsername" name="username"/>
  <input type="hidden" id="hiddenPassword" name="password"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Login"/>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
  $("#theForm").submit(function() {
    $("#hiddenUsername").val($("#username").val());
    $("#hiddenPassword").val($("#password").val());
  });
  $("#username,#password").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      $("#theForm").submit();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: `$("#password").val()` will not work for an `input[type=password]`, because it would compromise the security of the password